# How to fix segue showing a grey screen

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode6, segue, swift5

I wanted to create a segue going from FirstViewController to DetailViewController, but when I write

```
        let detailVC = DetailViewController()
        detailVC.result = indexPath.row
        print(detailVC.result)
        self.present(detailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

, all it presents is a grey/transparent screen. How can I fix this?

````
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        
        cell.typeLabel.text = "Name: \(posts[indexPath.row].typeOfFood)"
        cell.titleLabel.text = "Title: \(posts[indexPath.row].title)"
        cell.locationLabel.text = "Location: \(posts[indexPath.row].location)"
        cell.nameLabel.text = "Name: \(posts[indexPath.row].name)"
        return cell
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//        print("Select Row \(indexPath.row)")
        var result = indexPath.row
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
//        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: nil)
        let detailVC = DetailViewController()
        detailVC.result = indexPath.row
        print(detailVC.result)
        self.present(detailVC, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }
} ```
````

Comment: I was expecting it to simply show the DetailViewController. I did design a View Controller linked to a swift ViewController file called DetailViewController. How would you ask the storyboard for its instance?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the phrase `DetailViewController()`. That's not you get the detail view controller you designed in the storyboard.

Instead, give the view controller you designed in the storyboard an identifier, and ask the *storyboard* for that view controller by calling this method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller

Now cast that view controller down to DetailViewController and go from there.